# SMPS with two outputs ,12v 3A(max) , 24V 2A(max)

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]

Hi all , I am new to designing circuits.
I am building an SMPS using the fairchild Semi FSGM300N Power switch.
here is the datasheet
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1526530.pdf
they have given a application design (the above diagram).

how can I make changes in this circuit so that I can get two outputs, that is ,12v 3A and 24V 2A.

now I have designed an SMPS with fairchild design tool and the circuit schematic is given below , can anyone explain me the functionality of this circuit? means exactly how it gives me Vo1=24V 2A and Vo2=12v 3A ?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The demo board circuit you have linked is really only good enough for a power output of about 25 watts (14V@1A plus 5V@2A = about 25W). Every part would virtually need to change if you wanted a power output of 84 watts (12V@3A plus 24V@2A). So forget about modifying this design - it won't achieve what you want it to.

Try looking for a device from power integrations such as the topswitch. They have reference designs that are more suitable for your power range.

[image]

Also, you can get the transformers from [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CHIQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.premiermag.com%2Fpdf%2Fpol.pdf&ei=coRPU_v9JsLAPNTVgeAJ&usg=AFQjCNGXnPNDg_JF6zF1IsjuMOhzEmiChA&bvm=bv.64764171,d.ZWU) (Premier Magnetics). Note the part TSD-2645 that uses the TOP249 top switch - this can provide 24V and 5V out: -

[image]

Comment: how can I get output of 24v 2A , and 12v 3A in this above circuit? what I will have to change ?

Comment: @Priyanka My intention is to get you a lot closer to a feasible solution than what you had with your circuit. 24V is present so no worries about that. Converting 5V to 12V is a turns ratio issue on the transformer and premier magnetics may have a transformer that exactly fits the bill. Nobody here is going to do fine-tuning design for you. You have to take on-board some responsibility for taking an idea forward.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly complex power supply design.  As you say that you are new to designing circuits, I would recommend starting out on something more basic.  The datasheet that you referenced doesn't give enough information to show us how to change the outputs, and it also demonstrates how to construct the custom transformer required for their demonstration circuit!  This project would intimidate me a bit, and I've been doing this for more than a decade :)

If I haven't scared you off, then the place to start your project is at Fairchild's Power Supply [WebDesigner](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/support/design-tools/power-supply-webdesigner/).  They assume you will use this WebDesigner, which is why they don't give full information in the datasheet.

You will tell it your design parameters, and it will give you suggested circuitry and components.  Including custom transformer specifications :)

Good luck, and be safe with the input voltages!

Comment: I have designed the circuit using fairchild design tool as u had told me. Can you please explain me its functionality? step by step

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Fairchild's IC using their application note is great way to learn how flybacks work.
Here is one : [AN-4137](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-4137.pdf).

And if your are using the TOP Series Power Integartion's ICs. Use this : [AN-16](http://download.21dianyuan.com/download.php?id=50695)

Changing these type of circuits, without knowing exactly what you are doing, is really dangerous. Any failure somewhere will result in blowing up of the mosfet (or internal mosfet if you are using one). I have burned a lot of these before, even by changing the tiniest part of the circuit. So make your moves carefully.

Answer (score 0):

use this simple circuit to get 12v 5a 
[image]